# NSTableView visual issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview, nstablecolumn

Can someone tell me what might cause this white rectangle in the column to appear? Thanks.
[image]

Thanks!

EDIT: If i resize that table column it goes away.

Comment: Under what circumstances does it appear in the first place? What information are you putting into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this question I just asked. It may be the same problem.

[NSTableView redraw not updating display, selection sticking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638702/nstableview-redraw-not-updating-display-selection-sticking)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might be a view floating above the table view.

Comment: It's not. I assure you that. Also, if I resize the table column, then it goes away. Thanks for the input though.